# MySQL remote access trouble?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database set up on a godaddy server. It is configured to allow remote access, and there are a couple of websites I'm running which need to access this data. It works when accessed from another godaddy site, and I can connect from my development environment both at work and home. We recently set up hosting with mydomain.com.

Here is the code block that triggered it:

```
function connect(){
    $servername = "XX.XX.XXX.XX";
    $dbusername = "databaseusername";
    $dbpassword = "mahpassword";
    $dbname = "databasename";
    try{
      $newMysql = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$dbname, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    }
        catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'connection Failed: '. $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
}
```

and now I'm getting this error message on the new site:

```
connection Failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XXX.XX' (111)
```

The only problems I can think of is that either for some reason there are a limited number of IP addresses the MySQL database will connect to by default (which seems squirrely), I'm getting blocked by a firewall on the MySQL server (again.. doesn't make sense to me), or there is some setting on the mydomain hosting server disallowing remote requests (?)

I'm new to this kind of thing, so I'm open to any suggestions. I could probably just set up another database on the new site, but I don't want the hassle of keeping them synchronized if I don't need to. What might be wrong? Are there any workarounds?

[edit]
connected to remote database via console `(mysql -h XX.XX.XXX.XX ...)`, the privileges were found under the information_schema database, a quick `select * from SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` and `select * from USER_PRIVILEGES` shows that `'databaseusername'@'%'` has sufficient privileges. Not that it helped me any, but maybe it'll help someone down the road.
[/edit]

Comment: The "Can't connect" message is likely a firewall block.  Verify that your host permits remote connections, as many do not.

Comment: Can you run `mysql -h XX.XX.XXX.XX -u databaseusername -p` from a console?

Comment: Yes, works from console.

Comment: There are 2 layers of security (probably) 1. firewall 2. MySQL user privileges. It'll be one or the other.

Comment: @Pete definitely not MySQL user privileges problem.In such case "Access denied" message will appears.

Comment: @rkosegi - Yep. So it must be a firewall.

Comment: @Pete Yes, After spending about an hour on hold, I was made aware that godaddy servers that allow 'direct/remote database access' still blocks other known hosting servers. I'll just have to clone the database on the mydomain server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been more than a year since I asked this question, I suppose I need to answer it just to close it.

It turns out that godaddy had blocked mydomain.com servers via firewall ("Remote access" was limited). so in order to accomplish what I wanted to do, I had to copy and store the database on both sites.